# If one is allergic to bread, what should he do for Challah and Matzah?

Tags: halacha, matzah, bread, challah-shabbat-bread

Let's say that someone is allergic to bread. All five grains. Not fatally, but enough that it causes a serious allergic reaction (say, to a degree that he would be allowed to take medicine on Shabbos). What should he do for Challah and Matzah? Do we apply oneis rachmana patrei? Does it depend on how allergic he is?

Comment: Not a duplicate. That one offers the possibility of oat. In this version he can't even have that.

Comment: My granddaughter used oat matzah on Pesach as even with the allergy, that was usable (if only for hamotzi). It is a matter of how much of an allergy one has and what the effect is.

Comment: @donielf I'm not sure this isn't a dupe (ignoring the matza part) the gluten answer doesn't work according to all Poskim and the question does say outright that the person can't have motzi.

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer regarding oats doesn't apply to your question, but @DoubleAA's [higher-voted] answer would seem to.